# Understanding the significance between observed and expected values in contingency table

Tags: statistical-significance, chi-squared-test, contingency-tables

Below is a table which I would like to understand the significance of each specific cell in terms of "is what I'm observing actually statistically significant"? I am aware of the Chi square test but this summarises the whole table's significance - I would like to look at the significance of each specific observation count.

[image]

Comment: What is observe A, Obs. B etc. ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I'm aware, you can't look at the significance individually. You can look at each cell's contribution to the overall chi-square statistic to see which might be contributing the most to any statistical significance (should there be any).